# Are 3.000 requests per second fast enough for my nodejs app on an AWS EC2 t4g.nano instance?

Tags: node.js, nginx, workbench

I have an **AWS EC2 t4g.nano (2 vCPU & 0.5 GiB memory)** server with this configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu
- Web Server: NGINX
- App Server: NodeJS

The app is entirely in Nodejs - aprox 50 MB (all modules included). The app is I/O intensive and I use just one core. I left the other one free for the moment, with the intention of using it as a worker (for CPU intensive operations). It uses the native **HTTP module** and besides that, the **REDIS** and **MYSQL2** modules (for getting data from DB and caching the most used one - other config etc. are kept in object dictionary). I was careful to use as much as possible promises in order not to block the main thread.

I work benched with Loader.io and I constantly get about **3.000 requests/seconds** after the flow stabilizes. Please see the graph: [Loader.io workbench for 3.000 r/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM19E.jpg)

That is the top limit. If I try more than 3.000 r/s, requests start to be dropped and the waiting time starts to oscillate a lot.

**My question**: is it a good number 3.000 r/s for the specifications of the **EC2 server**, or should I still try to optimise something?

Thank you very much!

Comment: For a single CPU, that seems pretty good.  That means you're using no more than 0.3 ms of nodejs CPU per request in executing your Javascript (redis and mysql2 are in other processes and may be using other CPU resources).

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you very much! I am quite a novice with NodeJs and it was difficult to understand ASYNC coming from a PHP burdened past. I tried to keep the JavaScript in main thread as slim as possible and to delegate everything I can into promises and callbacks, as I understood that this way some of the work is done by the kernel. I might be wrong, as well...

Comment: @jfriend00 I saw now that you have a HUGE reputation on Stackoverflow and I thank you again for the time you took to comment here! Could you please tell me what would be the „max” reasonable time that Nodejs should take to process the request, if there is such a standard, let's say? Big thanks!

Comment: There is no absolute as it depends upon your system configuration, OS, etc...  If you want to devise your own test, then just set up a web server that all it does is immediately send a short response to any incoming http request.  That will allow you to benchmark the basic overhead of your http library inside of nodejs.  Scalability will only go down from there as you add code to actually do something useful.

Comment: @jfriend00 That was my approach. First I returned a response directly from NGINX without proxying to Nodejs. Then I proxyed from NGINX to a minimum HTTP Server in Nodejs with just a minimum payload: `res.writeHeader( 200, [['Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8']]).end("OK"))`. From then on, I started puting more _meat_ on the app by importing the minimum modules, creating the object dictionary, defining callbacks and promises. Thank you very much for your time and the smart tips you gave me through your answers!